# Intent-filter to intercept package-specific intents to Play Store

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm trying to open my app when a play-store link (on a webpage) targeting my app. I tried the following intent-filters, but I can't get it working:

*HTTPS link*

```
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Catch web intents for Google Play Store -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="play.google.com"/>
            <!--<data android:path="/store/apps/details?id=my.app"/>-->
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

The problem with that is that the Play Store is always opened. I tried to reset it's settings to remove the "Default action" but with no luck. I have the behavior whether I'm using an intent from the ADB shell (`$ am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app`) or from Firefox mobile when browsing on my app's page and click on the small Android icon in the address bar). Using that configuration, I should be catching ALL Play Store intents (as I commented the Path) but it's not the case. Is it overriding the chooser dialog?

*Market link*

```
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Catch Google Play Store intents for FB Messenger -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="market"/>
            <data android:host="details"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

For that second intent, I catch it successfully but I couldn't find a way to make it specific to my app. I tried to play with the other  fields but with no luck. (`$ am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d market://details?id=my.app`)

**So in the end, my question is: "How to intercept all 'Open play store' intents from a webpage targeting the package my.app, whether it is market://details… or https://play.google.com… URIs?"**

Answer (score 0):

Just to open the application with app store link.App will be open if installed.if application is not install you will be redirected to playstore.

```
if(ReykjavikUtils.isPackageInstalled("com.whatsapp" , MainActivity.this)){
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    startActivity(i);
} else
{
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
}


public static boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, Context context) {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I should have added that the links are present on a website, targeting my app. It's not from another app. I edit the question to add that detail.